# Manually building a string in C using pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers

The following code compiles and executes well with mingw32 on Windows.

```
int main() {
    char *s;
    *s = 65;
    *(s+1) = 66;
    *(s+2) = 0;
    printf("%s", s);
}
```

This outputs AB. However, when I run the same code on an online compiler like ideone, I get a runtime error. [Here](http://ideone.com/aw8kEj) is the link to the code in ideone. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: You need to allocate memory for storing character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go step-by-step and understand why it happens, first:

```
char *s;
```

variables in C are not initialized to some constant value like in some other programming languages, in C they get some sort of a random garbage value - means defining an `int` for example can result with an int with `0`, `-2` or `193821`. Same with pointers, they ARE variables, it gets a garbage value which means that it points to SOMEWHERE, unknown where too.

```
*s = 65;
```

You didn't assign any memory to it, you just said "Where S points to ? Okay, go there - assign 65", the computer won't do anything but that, it'll go and assign 65 there (nobody said the memory there is available). Same happens in the next tow lines, no memory assigned - but you assign to it anyway. Sometimes it'll work, sometimes it won't.
If you wanted to assign memory you'd use `malloc` but the reason the code won't work online is because the site - unlike most compilers - won't allow it, the code probably runs on its servers and the site won't want any undefined behaviors or problems in its memory - then the site won't enable you to assign values to memory that you didn't get or even request for. The site protects itself, when they built the site they developed it so no one can make it crash, you probably won't be able to cause them a buffer overflow simply by using gets - it probably has predefined inputs - and they probably won't let you defining an integer array with trillion elements :P

Comment: Thanks for explicitly pointing out that I was declaring a pointer, which pointed to some place random. Its clearer now.

Comment: `static` and global variables in C _are_ initialized to some value.  Non-`static` local ones like `char *s` inside `main()` are not.

Comment: @chux its not by some value, its 0, as mandated by the standard.

Comment: @chux I don't know, I was talking from knowledge but mostly experience, I just now ran a program (after your comment) compiled with GCC that prints a pointer and prints an integer, both not initialized and BOTH had some random garbage value :P

Comment: @hexa  §6.7.9 10 specifies in part "...if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer; — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero; ...".  So although pointers with a value of 0 must equate to `NULL`, `NULL` itself need not be explicitly 0.  Thus it is allowable, and IMO certainly unusual, for a pointer to be initialized to `NULL` and not 0.

Comment: @user3195614 A test with different variable types is not the issue.  Try your test with different storage classes.  With and without `static`.

Answer (score 4):

```
*s = 65;
*(s+1) = 66;
*(s+2) = 0;
```

All these three statements invoke undefined behavior as `s` pointer is not initialized.

For example use this (this is only for the example, a better way would be to use the array directly):

```
 char bla[3];
 char *s = bla;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to allocate memory for your string. As it stands, your code is exhibiting undefined behavior, and will likely cause a segmentation fault. Try something like this:

```
int main() {
    char *s = malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);
    *s = 65;
    *(s+1) = 66;
    *(s+2) = 0;
    printf("%s", s);
    free(s);
}
```

Note that you should check for the case where `malloc` returns `NULL`.

Comment: Yes you want to malloc

Comment: Minor: Consider `malloc(3 * sizeof *s);` or `malloc(3);` as `sizeof(char)` is _always_ 1.

Answer (score 1):

*s* is merely a pointer to something. It does not allocate any space to hold the string. In mingw32 you're lucking out that you didn't overwrite something critical, while in ideone, it's catching the fact that you're writing where you shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are invoking **undefined behaviour**.

When you dereference at `*s = 65`, s is not initialized and pointing to an **undefined memory address**, it is a local variable and as such, it gets random data. The same happens with the next lines.

Ideone not crashing was pure luck.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare `char *s` there is no memory allocated for the pointer. Either you can allocate memory by using `malloc` or by pointing `s` to an array like `char arr[3]; s = are`.

Results are undefined if you access an uninitialised pointer.